# Resources (resx) with Python

Tags: python, resources, module, resx

Do you know of any Python module for resources (resx files) manipulation?

P.S.: I know I could write a custom wrapper on top of base XML processor available, I'm just checking out before going to hack my own code...

Comment: do you have any pointers on how you did it. I have a usecase where I need to create a .resx file from my models data which consists of translations.

Comment: I'm afraid it's been a while since I asked this question, and since then I moved on to other things.

Answer (score 1):

This question [Resources (resx) maintenance in big projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806305/resources-resx-maintenance-in-big-projects) has an answer pointing to some .NET source code for a tool to manage RESX resources. Since [IronPython](http://www.codeplex.com/IronPython) can interface with any existing .NET objects written in C#, you should be able to adapt that RESX tool source code into an object that you can then use in IronPython.